# How to make ruler in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make such ruler in SwiftUI https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl4Az.jpg. I wonder is it possible to do it with only one ForEach? Is it right implementation?

```
struct Ruler: View {

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { num in
            HStack(spacing: 40) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
                    Divider()
                        .frame(width: 1.5, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.white)
                    Text("\(num)")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .bold))
                }
                ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Divider()
                        .frame(width: 1.5, height: 15)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .padding(.bottom, -14)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 40)
    .background(Color.black)
}
}

struct Ruler_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      Ruler()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to have each portion of the ruler be a `Shape` with an associated `enum` to represent the tick marks needed. Each iteration of the shape would draw exactly 1 section of the ruler. By doing this, you gain more control and more precision as to how to draw it, with 1 `ForEach` and simple repeatability. The shape could be defined as:

```
struct Unit: Shape {
    
    let num: Int
    let ticks: [Tick]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let distance = rect.width / CGFloat(ticks.count)
        var path = Path()
        var x = rect.minX
        for tick in ticks {
            switch tick {
            case .major:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.minY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.maxY))
            case .mid:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.maxY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.maxY - 16))
            case .minor:
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.maxY))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.maxY - 8))
            }
            x += distance
            print("tick")
        }
        return path
    }
}

enum Tick {
    case major, mid, minor
}
```

Then your view would simplify to this:

```
struct Ruler: View {
    
    let ticks: [Tick] = [.major, .minor, .mid, .minor, .mid, .minor, .mid, .minor]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { num in
                    Unit(num: num, ticks: ticks)
                        .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("\(num)")
                                .padding(.trailing, 2)
                                .foregroundColor(.white),
                            alignment: .topTrailing
                        )
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding(.top, 2)
            .padding(.bottom, 1)
            .background(Color.black)
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! Great implementation!

Comment: Shape is a good solution compared to Dividers